# Не получается получить имя и фамилию аккаунта VK через API

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api

Пишу приложение, которое будет получать информацию из VK.
Застопорился на запросе получения имя и фамилии авторизированного пользователя.

```
VKRequest request = VKApi.Account.getProfileInfo();
```

Студия `Account` подчёркивает красным и ничего не получается.

Подскажите, как правильно написать этот запрос. В каком виде придёт ответ?

Comment: Что пишет, когда наводите на Account?alt+enter пробовали?

Comment: А что студия пишет по поводу Account? Обычно в IDEA помимо подчеркивания еще и какие-то сообщения показываются.

Comment: При наведении курсора пишет "Cannot resolve symbol 'Account'

alt+enter предлагает:
create class  'Account'
create inner class  'Account'
rename reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я помню в sdk нет функции для аккаунтов такого типа как ваша, но можно сделать так

```
String token = VKSdk.getAccessToken().accessToken;
VKParameters parameters = VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.ACCESS_TOKEN, token);

VKRequest request = new VKRequest("account.getProfileInfo", parameters);

request.executeWithListener(new VKRequestListener(MainActivity.this)
{
    @Override
    public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
        super.onComplete(response);

        String status = "";

        try {

            JSONObject jsonObject = response.json.getJSONObject("response");

            String first_name = jsonObject.getString("first_name");
            String last_name = jsonObject.getString("last_name");
            String screen_name = jsonObject.getString("screen_name");
            status = jsonObject.getString("status");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
});

public class VKRequestListener extends VKRequest.VKRequestListener {


private final Context mContext;

public VKRequestListener(Context context)
{
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public void onError(VKError error) {
    super.onError(error);
    if(error.errorCode == 14)
    {
        VKCaptchaDialog vkCaptchaDialog = new VKCaptchaDialog(error);
        vkCaptchaDialog.show(mContext, new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Открой этот метод (`getProfileInfo()`) и посмотри как он работает, как и куда получает данные.

А выделяет красным, видимо не находит его, его там может и не быть, а если все же есть, то его надо подключить (Eclipse это сочетание клавиш <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>).

Answer (score 0):

```
VKRequest profileInfo1 = VKApi.users().get();
```

Вот такой запрос с пустыми параметрами возвращает имя и фамилию авторизированного юзера.